# APReleaseProcess_Extension customize code doesn't work in Acumatica ERP Version 2017 R2

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica, erp

I've tried to customize button release in Release AP Documents screen.
[image]

And then I used the following code:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APReleaseProcess_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APReleaseProcess>
  {
  public delegate List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProcDel(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, PXResult<APInvoice, 
                                                    CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor> res, bool isPrebooking, 
                                                    out List<INRegister> inDocs);
  [PXOverride]
  public List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, 
                                        PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor> res, 
                                        bool isPrebooking, 
                                        out List<INRegister> inDocs, ReleaseDocProcDel del)
  {
      je.RowInserting.AddHandler<GLTran>((sender, e) =>
      {
          GLTran glTran = e.Row as GLTran;
          APTran apTran = PXResult<APTran>.Current;
          if (glTran != null && apTran != null)
          {
              APTranExt apTranEx = PXCache<APTran>.GetExtension<APTranExt>(apTran);
              if (apTran != null && apTranEx.UsrJobOrderNbr != null)
              {
                  GLTranExt glTranEx = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>(glTran);
                  glTranEx.UsrJobOrderNbr = apTranEx.UsrJobOrderNbr;
              }
          }

          //APInvoice apInv = PXResult<APInvoice>.Current;
          APInvoice apInv = PXSelect<APInvoice,
                                Where<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<GLTran.refNbr>>,
                                    And<APInvoice.docType,
                                        Equal<Required<GLTran.tranType>>>>>.Select(sender.Graph, glTran.RefNbr, glTran.TranType);

          if (glTran != null && apInv != null)
          {
              GLTranExt glTranEx = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>(glTran);
              glTranEx.UsrInvoiceNbr = apInv.InvoiceNbr;
          }

          APTaxTran apTaxTran = PXResult<APTaxTran>.Current;
          if (glTran != null && apTaxTran != null)
          {
              APTaxTranExt apTaxTranEx = PXCache<APTaxTran>.GetExtension<APTaxTranExt>(apTaxTran);
              if (apTaxTran != null && apTaxTranEx != null)
              {
                  GLTranExt glTranEx = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>(glTran);
                  glTranEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur = apTaxTranEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur;
                 }

              }

          }
              );
          return del(je, ref doc, res, isPrebooking, out inDocs);
      }
  }
}
```

I tried to debug this code but the break point didn't hit, does it the correct method to customize the button release ?
Does anyone know regarding to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In Acumatica Customization Project Editor, in the `CODE` section, add a graph extension on APReleaseProcess. Then open the generated code file and use action button `OVERRIDE METHOD`. Select the target method in the list and click on `SAVE` button. This will insert the proper event handler for the Acumatica version you are using:

[image]

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APReleaseProcess_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APReleaseProcess>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProcDelegate(JournalEntry je, APRegister doc, Boolean isPrebooking, ref List<INRegister> inDocs);
    [PXOverride]
    public List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, APRegister doc, Boolean isPrebooking, ref List<INRegister> inDocs, ReleaseDocProcDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      return baseMethod(je,doc,isPrebooking,inDocs);
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hugues, thanks for your answer. Regarding of your code, it seems no difference with my code. But I didn't do the step of override method for exsiting BLC. Does this step is mandatory for override the BLC ? And if I do this step, does the breakpoint will be hit in debug processing ?

Comment: Method parameters look different but you did use PXOverride in your answer which is correct. Regarding breakpoints, can you demonstrate symbols are properly loaded? Or better, can you throw an exception instead of troubleshooting with breakpoints? And in screenshot no rows are selected for processing, did you process a row by selecting it first before clicking release?